# How to fix cross-origin error when request to Kylo API

Tags: rest, cors, kylo

I have a running instance of a Kylo Sandbox in a server called: `kyloserver`. I am trying to access Kylo API from my website, running in `localhost:8080`.

I try to use Search API calling url:

```
http://kyloserver:8400/proxy/v1/feedmgr/search?q=mary&rows=20&start=0
```

and using Basic Authentication in header like this (javascript):

```
Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(this.username + ":" + this.password)
```

The response is:

> Failed to load
>   http://kyloserver:8400/proxy/v1/feedmgr/search?q=mary&rows=20&start=0:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

If I use swagger by logging into the UI I can get the results properly.

How can I access the API successfully?

(Kylo Version: 0.8.3)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kylo has disabled CORS support by default. You'll need to write a plugin to override the default configuration with one that enables CORS:
https://github.com/Teradata/kylo/blob/v0.8.4/services/service-app/src/main/java/com/thinkbiganalytics/server/DefaultWebSecurityConfigurer.java

Comment: Thanks! Does it make sense to open an issue and suggest to be able to enable CORS from config i.e. application.properties??

Comment: Yes, you can open a JIRA. Then the Kylo team can decide how to proceed. https://kylo-io.atlassian.net/

Answer (score 0):

Finally I decided to create a Proxy web service which is hosted in the same server as Kylo, which just redirects the requests from the web to the Kylo Service.